# Nuxt content v1 override markdown renderer components

Tags: nuxt.js, markdown, clipboard.js, nuxt-content

**Problem:**
I am looking for a way to have a little bit more control over `nuxt-content` (v1) markdown renderer. To be more specific looking for add copy button / title to rendered code blocks with some customizability.

I appreciate any sort of guidance. Thanks in advance.

**What I have tried:**
I have found a lost solution with `theme-docs` I believe project is not any more supported.
https://content.nuxtjs.org/v1/v1/examples/docs-theme
I have also found a solution to override markdown components for `v2` but it is not available for `v1`.
https://mokkapps.de/blog/how-to-create-a-custom-code-block-with-nuxt-content-v2

Comment: Not sure about the specific details but you could probably use some CSS to append it to where you want + add some listener to the button for it to copy your code.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. As far as I know, I need some HTML elements in order to style them with CSS, is it right? Or can I make it appear irrelevant button (not a child) to use it appears and copy on the mouseover code block?

Comment: I can create a button component to be injected on code bock on hover. But then, how can I inject nuxt component dynamically?

Comment: Why do you need a nuxt component specifically? You could probably use a mix of template ref + render function but some vanilla HTML + listener to call the clipboard API should be enough too.

Comment: I do not need to use components. However, I believe it would be the neatest way to implement it.